# how to install WordPress jupiter-v6.7.0.zip

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

i'm installing but get this error.

> Installing plugin from uploaded file: jupiter-v6.7.0.zip
> Unpacking the package…

Installing the plugin…

The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.

Plugin installation failed.

Return to Plugin Installer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a wordpress theme as an plugin.

Try going to 'Appearance' > 'Themes' and clicking 'Add New' at the top  of the page, after the refresh click on 'upload theme' again at the top of the page.

Select your Theme and upload it to your wordpress site, once the theme is uploaded you should see Jupiter in your themes list, activate the theme and you should be done.